# How to search using similar characters in random positions in Microsoft SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a query that would allow the user to use a variation of characters while searching for a result. The character positions are completely random. We use special characters È,Š,Ć,Č,Ž and Đ so all of the variations have to match, because most of users do not know how to spell correctly.

Example:

```
MISIC
MISIĆ
MISIČ
MIŠIC
MIŠIĆ
MIŠIČ
```

Comment: Use a collation which is "special character" insensitive.

Comment: which database ?

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Microsoft SQL, fixed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search it by using `COLLATE`

```
SELECT *
FROM TableNAme
WHERE
   columnName COLLATE Like '%MISIC%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

- latin1 makes the server treat strings using charset latin 1,
  basically ascii.
- CI specifies case-insensitive, so "ABC" equals to "abc".
- AI specifies accent-insensitive,so 'ü' equals to 'u'.

for more information collation go through the 
[Collete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms144250(v=sql.105))

refereance : @JINO SHAJI

---

as per @Adephx comment this is working as expected with few modification

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [COLUMN] LIKE '%NAME%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [COLUMN] LIKE '%NAME%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI  - Working variant.

Answer (score 0):

Applying COLLATION is a great practice, especially if we want to get rid of ***all*** Accent-marks, however, if we need more granular control over individual accent-characters (È,Š,Ć,Č,Ž), we can do something like below to selectively compare individual accent-characters.

Most DBMSs provide string-comparison functionality based on how the words sound (pronounced).  SQL Server provides two built-in functions for this: SOUNDEX() and DIFFERENCE(). In this scenario we can do this:

```
IF (DIFFERENCE('MISIC', 'MISIĆ')>=4) 
    AND (DIFFERENCE('MISIC', 'MISIČ')>=4)
    AND (DIFFERENCE('MISIC', 'MIŠIC')>=4)
    AND (DIFFERENCE('MISIC', 'MIŠIĆ')>=4)
    AND (DIFFERENCE('MISIC', 'MIŠIČ')>=4)
    PRINT 'Same word'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Different word.'
```

Actually, in many languages '**Š**' sounds quite different than '**S**', therefore SQL Server considers them as less-compatible, but here is a workaround to impose equivalence:

```
WITH words AS (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(N'MISIĆ,MISIČ,MIŠIC,MIŠIĆ,MIŠIČ', ','))
SELECT 
    value,
    CASE WHEN (DIFFERENCE('MISIC', replace(value,'Š','S'))>=4) 
        THEN 'Same word' 
        ELSE 'Not same' 
    END AS 'Comparison'
FROM words
```

*Output*:

```
value   comparison
-----   ----------
MISIĆ   Same word
MISIČ   Same word
MIŠIC   Same word
MIŠIĆ   Same word
MIŠIČ   Same word
```

> Above example will work in "Microsoft SQL Server 2016" or above, note that the STRING_SPLIT() function is only used to iterate over the array of words/strings, this function is not available in SQL Server 2014 or below.

Hope this helps.